# CSS a straight horizontal line with 2 different colors

Tags: css

It's 2013 now and im just wondering if there has come a better way to achieve this? Is there a way to do this with just one element?

```
div.linetop { border-top: 1px solid #111111; }
div.linebottom { border-top: 1px solid #292929; }

// make a line
<div class="linetop"></div>
<div class="linebottom"></div>
```

## Edit

This is what happens with HR the first pixel is grey :/ (im using chrome btw dont have any other browsers):

Tried both:

```
hr {
border-top: 1px solid #111111; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #292929; 
}
```

and

```
hr {
display: block;
height: 0;
padding: 0;
border-top: 1px solid #111111; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #292929; 
}
```

[image]

## Edit

Solved it! Simply adding border:none before

```
hr {
border: none;
border-top: 1px solid #111111; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #292929; 
}
```

Comment: `hr` tag with `border-top` and `border-bottom`.....

Comment: CSS gradients or pseudo-elements instead of extra elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `<hr>` tag, and use both `border-top` and `border-bottom`:

```
hr {
  border-top: 1px solid #111111; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #292929; 
}
```

The HTML is simply: `<hr>`.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/nrEfm/1/)

Comment: @Kaka Show a picture of what your div solution did differently, and also your markup/css which affects this/link to your website.

Comment: Cant you see that its a grey "dot" in the beginning?

Comment: @Kaka Interesting how it seemed to have a border-left. Glad it's solved anyhow :)

Answer (score 6):

Possible alternative solutions:

### 1. CSS gradients - [support info](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients)

**HTML**: `<div class='v1'></div>`

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.v1 {
  background: linear-gradient(#111 50%, #292929 50%) no-repeat 50% 75%;
  background-size: 80% 2px;
}
```

### 2. a `:before` pseudo-element & a `box-shadow` - [support info](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow)

**HTML**: `<div class='v2'></div>`

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.v2 { position: relative; }
.v2:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%; bottom: 20%; left: 10%;
  height: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px #292929;
  background: #111;
  content: '';
}
```

### 3. `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements - [support info](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent)

**HTML**: `<div class='v3'></div>`

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.v3 { position: relative; }
.v3:before, .v3:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%; bottom: 20%; left: 10%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #111;
  content: '';
}
.v3:after { margin-bottom: -1px; background: #292929; }
```

## [***demo***](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/pxvDL)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<hr>` tag, and use `border-top` and `border-bottom` to define you two lines color:

```
hr {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #08f; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
#hrtag {
border-bottom: green 2px solid;
border-top: red 2px solid;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<hr id="hrtag"/>
```

If you want it to be a class then just swap the # for . and id for class. In the CSS, you can change the color to whatever you want. This was tested in Chrome.

Comment: You may have other css that adds styles to hr tags.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try box-shadow,like this:

### HTML

```
<div class="hr"></div>
```

## CCS

```
.hr{
  border-top: 1px solid #111;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #292929;
}
```

Please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/Glzsv).